# How do I make a For..Each value not literal in % { dir IIS:\AppPools\$_.Name }

Tags: iis, wmi, powershell-2.0, application-pool, worker-process

**Here is what doesn't work**

`>dir IIS:\AppPools\ | % { dir IIS:\AppPools\$_.Name\WorkerProcesses }`

**More Info**

I want to use Powershell to get the PID of each Application pool.  I understand that I could use WMI to get the information like the command below, but I'm trying to use Powershell's WebAdministration module.

**WMI Approach (working sample)**

`Get-WmiObject -NameSpace 'root\WebAdministration' -class 'WorkerProcess' -ComputerName 'host' | select AppPoolName, ProcessId | ft -a`

```
AppPoolName                   ProcessId
-----------                   ---------
MSExchangePowerShellAppPool        5432
MSExchangeServicesAppPool          3604
MSExchangeOWAAppPool               7056
MSExchangeAutodiscoverAppPool      6012
DefaultAppPool                     3288
MSExchangeSyncAppPool              2944
```

**Powershell Approach  (not working sample.. help!)**

How do I combine the outputs of the two commands (perhaps as a single line) to also give me the PID for each app pool?

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>import-module WebAdministration
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>dir IIS:\AppPools

Name                     State        Applications
----                     -----        ------------
Classic .NET AppPool     Started
DefaultAppPool           Started      Default Web Site
                                      /Rpc
                                      /RpcWithCert
                                      /ArchiveProxy
MSExchangeAutodiscoverAp Started      /Autodiscover
pPool                                 /Autodiscover/bin
                                      /Autodiscover/help
MSExchangeECPAppPool     Started      /ecp
MSExchangeOWAAppPool     Started      /owa
                                      /owa/oma
                                      /ArchiveProxyOwa
MSExchangeOWACalendarApp Started      /owa/Calendar
Pool
MSExchangePowerShellAppP Started      /PowerShell
ool
MSExchangeServicesAppPoo Started      /EWS
l                                     /EWS/bin
MSExchangeSyncAppPool    Stopped      /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync
```

The second query I want to combine is this:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>dir IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool\WorkerProcesses  | fl


processId : 3904
Handles   : 89516
state     : Running
StartTime : 2/19/2013 10:34:57 PM
```

Comment: try dir IIS:\AppPools\ |select -expand name| % { dir IIS:\AppPools\$_\WorkerProcesses }

Comment: @Kayasax THAT WORKS!  If you post that as an answer I'll give you +25 rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just have to expand the property you need :

```
dir IIS:\AppPools\ |select -expand name| % { dir IIS:\AppPools\$_\WorkerProcesses }
```